# what does pointer to pointer do? char**

Tags: c

```
char x[16];
int y = 42 + 256;
char* p = &y;
int* q = p;
char** r = &p;
printf("%d %d %d\n", p, q, r);
```

why is the value of r always 12 units smaller than p and q? Thank you!

Comment: You should print pointers using `%p` format.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129128/memory-allocation-in-c/2129610#2129610

Comment: I'd avoid the phrase "double pointer". It's ambiguous. Use something like pointer-to-pointer instead to be clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double pointer is a pointer to pointer.

> why is the value of r always 12 units
>   smaller than p and q?

That won't stay if you move to another runtime or another operating system / compiler.

Answer (score 6):

What you're printing there are three memory addresses. Since those are allocated on the stack (assuming they're not global) I would expect something like:

```
2030 2026 2022
```

assuming a 32 bit machine and 4 byte pointers.

A double `*` is a pointer to a pointer. If you use correct types it becomes clearer.

```
char *str = "hello world";
```

`str` in this case is a pointer to a null-terminated sequence of characters.

```
char **p = &str;
```

means a pointer to a pointer to a string of characters.

I say "correct types" because you have, for example:

```
int y = 42 + 256;
char* p = &y;
```

Really this should be:

```
int *p = &y;
```

The usual reason to use a `char *` in this instance is to examine the individual bytes.

Answer (score 4):

Let's analyze your code line by line:

```
char x[16];
```

`x` is an "array [16] of `char`", i.e., it can store 16 `char` values.  You don't use `x` at all in your code, by the way.

```
int y = 42 + 256;
```

`y` is an `int` equal to 298.

```
char* p = &y;
```

`p` is a pointer to `char`, and you're trying to assign the address of an `int` to it.  If you want a pointer to an `int`, you should declare `p` as `int *p`, or if you want a generic pointer, you should declare it as `void *p`.  If you really want to do what you're doing, you need a cast: `char *p = (char *)&y;`.  The result of your initialization of `p` is that `p` points to the lowest addressed byte of `y`.

```
int* q = p;
```

`q` is of type `int *`, and `p` is of type `char *`.  Again, you need a cast.  Assuming the cast, the standard says this about your last two statements:

> A pointer to an object or incomplete type may be converted to a pointer to a different object or incomplete type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the pointed-to type, the behavior is undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the
>   result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

So, the net effect is as if you did: `int *q = &y;`.  So, `q` contains the address of `y`.

```
char **r = &p;
```

`r` is of type `char **`.  `&p` is of type `int **`.  Again, you need a cast at the least, but you can't portably convert an `int **` to a `char **`.  I am not sure why you're using `char **` anyway.  If you wanted the address of `p` in a variable, you should use `void *`, or assuming you really want `char`, use `char *`.

```
printf("%d %d %d\n", p, q, r);
```

You're printing pointers with `%d` format specifier.  `%d` takes an `int`, not a pointer.  You should use `%p` and cast `p`, `q`, and `r` to `void *` for printing.

Assuming I understood what you wanted to do, I rewrote your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int y = 42 + 256;
    void *p = &y;
    void *q = p;
    void *r = &p;
    printf("%p %p %p\n", p, q, r);
    return 0;
}
```

On my computer, this prints:

```
0x7fff5fbff7dc 0x7fff5fbff7dc 0x7fff5fbff7d0
```

`p` and `q` are obviously equal, and `r` is the address of the object `p`.

If I didn't understand your intent correctly, you have to tell us what you're trying to do and why.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, there's no guarantee about the value of r compared to p or q. Since you say it's smaller, I'd guess these are automatic variables in a function. What you're seeing is the fact that the compiler is (probably) allocating 4 bytes for each pointer, and you've allocated 3 of them, which works out to 12 bytes -- that's pretty much an accident though, not anything the C standard requires or anything like that. Just for example, on a 64-bit system, it's pretty likely you'd see different numbers.

A char ** is a pointer to a pointer to a char. A typical use would be creating a dynamic array of strings. It might be easier to follow if you started with something like:

```
typedef char *string;

string *string_array;
```

If you put those pieces together, it says: `char **string_array;`